# Why put a constructor function directly into a variable?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set up a variable and pass it constructor function essentailly like an anonymous type in c# but javascript doesnt seem to like it...

```
var aPerson = function Person(){

};


$(document).ready(function(){

  Person.prototype.age = 22;

  window.alert(aPerson .age);

});
```

Why cant I do this?

Comment: This code looks awfully familiar...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this edit to a prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359190/why-doesnt-this-edit-to-a-prototype-work)

Comment: Oh please, don't ask the same question twice!

Comment: sorry guys the question is actually different but similar...not sure if I should just roll into one question but that sort of doesnt get to the point....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Person` is only declared as part of your `aPerson` variable, but it needs to be defined explicitly (e.g. `function Person(){}`) before it can be used for prototypical inheritance. You need something more like this:

```
// Create a Person function object
function Person() {

};

// Modify that function's prototype
Person.prototype.age = 22;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // aPerson.__proto__ = Person.prototype
  var aPerson = new Person();

  // JS checks whether aPerson has age already set, if not, it checks
  // aPerson's prototype -- in which case it's given the value 22
  alert(aPerson.age);
});
```

Here's the deal: the property `prototype` works together with `new` by copying the `prototype` reference to the object (you can see what that entails by running `console.dir(aPerson)` in Chrome console, for example). JavaScript checks the original object itself first, then prototype to see whether a function or property exists. That means you can change the reference prototype `age` later and see the changes reflected in the original object. Also, you can declare your own `age` in the original object itself and have that override the prototype.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite certain you have to reference your function using `aPerson` rather than `Person` (externally).  Internally, you'd reference it using `Person`.

Alternatively, you could do this -

```
function Person() {

}

var aPerson = new Person();

$(function() {
  Person.prototype.age = 22;
  alert(aPerson.age) //22
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because `aPerson` doesn't have an age. You will have to call `new` for it to work.

```
var aPerson = function Person(){

};


$(document).ready(function(){

  Person.prototype.age = 22;
  bPerson = new Person();


  window.alert(bPerson.age);

});
```

Comment: but ive added age to the prototype of the Person class doesnt that mean that all objects will get the age?

Comment: Mind that `bPerson` is a global variable.

Comment: This doesn't work because [`Person` is not defined](http://jsfiddle.net/brymck/RkeCS/1/).

Comment: @Bryan: Correct, because of the [named function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#named-expr): `Person` is (or at least should be) only available inside of the function itself.

Comment: Marcel, yes the penny dropped I see now. Objects in javascript are passed by reference (or so Ive read) so I see whats going on now...thanks sorry if my questions are a bit basic...

Comment: @Bryan: so are you saying that aPerson actually hides the function constructor in this case?

Comment: Sorry guys jumping the gun but are we now saying that basically I have passed a reference to aPerson of the Person function. Its basically an anonymous function passed as a refernce to aPerson. So callng aPerson() is the same as calling Person() [if you could do the latter]..?

Comment: @Pete Right. You can actually set `aPerson` to inherit from `Person` using your format, but you need to define `Person` first. The above would work if you just put `function Person(){}` at the beginning.

Comment: @Pete, no, it's not anonymous, it's just that `Person` hasn't been defined yet. Mind you, this is still not the typical way to do it (most use `var foo = new Bar()` instead of `var foo = function Bar(){}`). You might want to check [the MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) for how you pattern things.